# Containerized WordPress cannot connect to database

Tags: wordpress, docker, mariadb

I am deploying WordPress as a containerized environment. Unfortunately the WordPress container cannot connect to the database instance. I am facing this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'mywpuser'@'192.168.64.3' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1659

The following is from within my database container:

`MariaDB [mysql]> select Host,User from user;`
`+———–+————-+`
`| Host | User |`
`+———–+————-+`
`| % | mywpuser |`
`| % | root |`
`| localhost | mariadb.sys |`
`| localhost | root |`
`+———–+————-+`

And when bashing into the mariadb container I am able to login to the database by using “mysql -u mywpuser -p”

So there obviously seem to be an issue when connecting with the given credentials from the WordPress container.

From the WordPress container I am able to successfully ping the database container.

Any idea on how to further troubleshoot that issue?

Comment: What does your `wp-config.php` file contains? there are constants for DB that you need to set, did you set them?

Comment: I did not change anything in that file. For the Wordpress container I am using the image "wordpress:5.7-php7.4" and for the database "mariadb:10".
Which constants are you thinking of and how can this be done from docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Solved that issue - there was a typo in the password of the database user :(